# How to get value in the cell that included tagName is "td" or "mat-cell"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My table has tagName "td" and "mat-cell". I have implement source as below sample that just get the value of the cell that has tagName is "td".

How to I got data that included tagName is "td" or "mat-cell"?

WebElement table = driver.findElement(taskListTablexpath);

```
    List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    int row_count = rows.size();
    System.out.println("Total Row: " + row_count);
    for (int row = 0; row < row_count; row = row + 2) {
        **List<WebElement> columns = rows.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("td"));**
        int columns_count = columns.size();
        System.out.println("Number of cells In Row " + row + " are " + columns_count);
        for (int column = 0; column < columns_count; column++) {
            String celtext = columns.get(column).getText();
            if (celtext == null)
                continue;
            System.out
                    .println("Cell Value of row number " + row + " and column number " + column + " Is " + celtext);
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------- ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also show us the HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be only one tag, if you want to match [`<td>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) elements which have `mat-cell` class [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp) - you need to amend your selector to be something like:

```
./td[contains(@class,'mat-cell')]
```

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Also be aware of [Table](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements/blob/master/htmlelements-java/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/htmlelements/element/Table.java) class available via [HtmlElements framework](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements), it makes working with [Tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) inlcuding [Angular Material tables](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) much easier

Answer (score 0):

findElements(By.Xpath(".//td | .//mat-cell"))